# Ajax dropdown not working in django while using adminLTE 3.0.5 template

Tags: django, ajax, dropdown, adminlte

I am using adminlte3 theme for my django project. In this project I have a form with ajax dependent drop-down control. In ADD PLANT form this drop-down (company) will be populated based on selection of country. But when I am using adminlte3 template it is not working.
Please see the github link.
https://github.com/shahidpharm/qtrack

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have already solved my problem. My problem was that I did not include below code inside content block in add_plant.html file.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
$("#id_country").change(function () {
var url = $("#pForm").attr("data-url_root"); // get the url of the `load_cities` view
var countryId = $(this).val(); // get the selected country ID from the HTML input
console.log(countryId);
$.ajax({ // initialize an AJAX request
url: url, // set the url of the request  localhost:8000/hr/ajax/load-cities/)
data: {
'country': countryId // add the country id to the GET parameters
},
success: function (data) { // `data` is the return of the `load_cities` view function
$("#id_company").html(data); // replace the contents of the city input with the data that came from the server
}
});
});
</script>
```

Now my code is working.
Feeling good.